# Checkbox filters with "only" button

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 6 checkboxes in a sidebar. When the page load they are already checked.

When you hover on each checkbox a "only" link on the right side is appearing.

I have one problem. When you click on the "only" link its working but when i am going to another checkbox after all are unchchecked and click on the "only" link it is not checking the checkbox.

Any advice how to do it?

```js
$('li').hover(function () {
    $(this).append('<a href="#" id="only-link">only</a>');

    $('li #only-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input:checkbox').not($(this).siblings('input:checkbox')).prop('checked', false);
    });
}, function () {
    $('#only-link').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
</ul>
```

There is one thing more... when there is any checkbox unchecked it will be nice to append a button "all" to check all the checkboxes again. How can be that achieved?

Comment: fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cx79cLt9/2/ . Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, uncheck every checkbox in this ul. Then check the clicked li's checkbox:

```js
// Add event listener for '#only-click' element
$(document).on('click', '#only-link', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var that = $(this);
   // Uncheck every checkbox in this ul
   that.closest('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
   // Check this li's checkbox
   that.closest('li').children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
});

// Perform hover handling
$('li').hover(function () {
    $(this).append('<a href="#" id="only-link">only</a>');
}, function () {
    $('#only-link').remove();
});

$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
   var thisUl = $(this).closest('ul');
   var checkedNum = thisUl.find('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').length;
   if (checkedNum == 0) {
      toggleAllBtn(thisUl, 'show');
   } else {
      toggleAllBtn(thisUl, 'hide');
   }
});

$(document).on('click', '#all', function() {
   $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
   $(this).remove();
});

function toggleAllBtn(thisUl, mode) {
   if (thisUl && mode) {
      var btn = $('<button id="all">All</button>');
      switch (mode) {
         case 'show':
           thisUl.append(btn);
           break;
         case 'hide':
           thisUl.find('#all').remove();
           break;
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is one thing more... when there is any checkbox unchecked it will be nice to append a button "all" to check all the checkboxes again. How can be that achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You do a minor changes

```js
$('li').hover(function() {
  $(this).append('<a href="#" id="only-link">only</a>');

  $('li #only-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true).not($(this).siblings('input:checkbox')).prop('checked', false);
  });
}, function() {
  $('#only-link').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Here is the changes..
$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true).not($(this).siblings('input:checkbox')).prop('checked', false);

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('li').hover(function () {
    $(this).append('<a href="#" id="only-link">only</a>');

    $('li #only-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         var ref = $(this);       
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
        ref.parent().find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    });
}, function () {
    $('#only-link').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('li').hover(function () {
    $(this).append('<a href="#" id="only-link">only</a>');

    $('li #only-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Uncheck all.
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      
        // Check the correct one.
        $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    });
}, function () {
    $('#only-link').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></li>
</ul>
```